# Git merge unexpectedly undoing previous commits

Tags: git, git-merge

We have recently switched to git as our vcs and we have run into a problem we ca
n't figure out.

Two days ago I pulled the code and made some changes. I committed them and pushed them. At the same time, my colleague made his own changes (with a small conflict). Later on he committed his changes, pulled the latest version from the git server, fixed the conflicts and then pushed his code.

Here is where the problem showed up, the changes I had made were reverted in the
 merge. All of them, even the ones in files where there was no conflict. If I run *git log*, I can see my commits normally and nothing reverting those changes. However when I run *git log -p -m*, it shows that during the merge, the code was simply changed back to what it was.

I have no idea why this happened and I would like to know how I can fix it. But
most importantly, how can we avoid that from happening again in the future?

Answer (score 0):

I have done this myself by 'fixing conflicts' by choosing the previous version rather than manually combining conflicting changes.  Could this be what happened to you?

use  git diff to compare the commits and possibly see this.

Comment: My colleague said he fixed the conflicts manually. However he used tortoisegit and he said it showed some error messages but he can't remember what they were. Is it possible that it's tortoisegit misbehaving?

Comment: Maybe.Nice thing about git - it is very hard to get it to forget anything - the evidence is there somewhere. Sometimes doing the research is very tedious.